# IntentService запускает активити через раз

Tags: android

Есть Alarm который, тригерит интент сервис, который в свою очередь запускает активити. Проблема в том, что сервис запускает активити постоянно через раз, то есть, первый раз запускает второй раз нет и так далее. Странно что именно через раз. Через раз для меня не приемлимо.

Comment: Ответ, который можно дать не видя кода: пусть аларм тригерит интент сервис в два раза чаще :)

Comment: Если убивать активити после старта, то активити запускается в 90% случаев на вскидку, но интересна причина, а не решение проблемы